# Integral of a Stepfunction: Analytical Motivation?

Tags: integration

For a stepfunction defined as:

f = $\sum_{k=1}^{K}c_k \chi_{I_k}$ where $\chi$ is the indicator function, $c_k \in \mathbb R$, the disjoint union of the closed intervals $I_k$ is [a,b] $\in \mathbb R$ and f is obviously in $C^0$.

I **know** that the integral of this function is $\sum_{k=1}^K c_k |I_k|$.

And although I can see how this is geometrically motivated, namely by adding up the squares of width $I_k$ and height $c_k$, I wonder how to derive the integral analytically, e.g. as one calculates the antiderivates of other functions.

Be aware that I am not familiar with the Lesbesgue Integral yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use linearity of integral. Then it all reduces to the question $\int_{\Bbb R}\chi_I$ for an interval $I$, say $I=[a,b]$. 
So we have
$$\int_{\Bbb R}\chi_I(x)dx=\int_I 1dx+\int_{\Bbb R\setminus I} 0dx =\int_a^b1dx=\\
=[x]_{x=a}^{b}=b-a=|I| $$
by the fundamental Newton-Leibneiz theorem, using that $(x\mapsto x)'=1$.